# Execute the query only if the string is NOT empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to run the query to enter data into the database only if you pressed the button, and if the various inputs are not empty. Now, it happens that if such an input contains white space the query is executed the same. I used empty but does not work. Why?

```
    if(isset($_POST['myButton']) and !empty($Var) and !empty($Var2) and !empty($Var3)) {
    $querySql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table(my_field, field, field_c, field_data) VALUES ('$Var', '$Var2', '$Var3', NOW())");
}
```

Comment: Also consider security issues, like SQL injection...

Comment: a good situation to use javascript validation to avoid the client server round trip for something as simple as whitespace

Comment: Full stack validation is always good to make sure everything is correctly formatted. Just don't rely only on JS validation or your script may become vulnerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the trim function to remove all characters like white spaces

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.trim.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `trim()`:

```
$Var = !empty($Var) ? trim($Var) : $Var;
$Var2 = !empty($Var2) ? trim($Var2) : $Var2;
$Var3 = !empty($Var3) ? trim($Var3) : $Var3;
if(isset($_POST['myButton']) and !empty($Var) and !empty($Var2) and !empty($Var3)) {
    //Do query
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [empty](https://www.php.net/empty)

It doesn't consider white space as empty. So you should use trim to remove white spaces before passing the variable into empty().

Answer (score 0):

`trim()` those variables first, ex:

```
$Var = trim($Var)
```